# Xcode 8.3.3 : in second Mac error: You have a valid iOS Distribution certificate on the developer website

Tags: ios, xcode8

I'm working a new machine (my other mac is at home) and I'm trying to archive and export a new version of app I'm working but I'm getting this error:

[image]

I download the distribution certificate from the apple development portal and I rebooted my Mac and Xcode but still have this error.

How can I make this work without reset my certificates?

I'll really appreciate your help

Comment: Please [search on an error](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bios%5D+your+account+already+has+a+valid+iOS+distribution+certificate) before posting.

Answer (score 0):

The key is the words "If your signing identity..." in the message. Read those words! The distribution profile for this app is not the problem. The problem is that you need the corresponding distribution *certificate* (identity). You cannot download that from the portal; that's not where it is. There can be only one, and it is currently located only in the keychain of the other machine; so the only way to get that onto this machine is to export it from the other machine.